# .toggleClass in my javaScript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to toggle between classes when I click on a '.switch'...

It works when I use the img as on click the selector:

```
$('img').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('casual')
})
```

But it won't work when I try to use the .switch class I've got:

```
$('.switch').click(function () {
    $('img').toggleClass('casual')
})
```

```js
$('img').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('casual')
})

$('.switch').click(function () {
    $('img').toggleClass('casual')
})
```

```css
.casual {
  background-image: url("images/pinkclouds.jpg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cover">
  <div class="intro">
    <img class="formal" src="images/photo.png" alt="profile-image" />
    <h2>Hello</h2>
  </div>
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked fine for me!

Comment: ok weird, I must be going wrong somewhere else... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding I think you want to change the `src` of image. In that case you can try the code bolow.

```js
$('img').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('casual')
})

$('#checkbox').click(function () {
    $('img').attr('src', 'https://archive.org/download/android_logo_low_quality/android_logo_low_quality.jpg')
})
```

```css
.casual {
  background-image: url("https://archive.org/download/android_logo_low_quality/android_logo_low_quality.jpg");
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/711687178921717760/DLSZLtLQ_400x400.jpg">
<div class="cover">
  <div class="intro">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
  </div>
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Let me know if you want something different.